# "By how" or "By the way" in this case?

Tags: difference

> By **how (or 'the way')** he reacted to the question, it was clear he was
> hiding something.

Both 'how' and 'the way' have the same meaning in this context. Like when we say:

> I like the way (or 'how') she dances.

However, in the first case, it strikes me as odd, probably because we can start a sentence with 'By the way' to mean 'Incidentally'.
So, my question is, do you recommend I should use 'how' to avoid misunderstanding, or is it clear from the context?

Comment: Both are fine. But how is less formal.

Answer (score 1):

Both "how" and "the way (that)" are perfectly acceptable in either sentence. I disagree with the comment saying that "how" is less formal; to me, they seem equivalent.